# Unexpected result from boolean_mask

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm calling `tensorflow.boolean_mask` using two compatible tensors, but the dimension is off example:

```
for m in range(self.class_dim):
    labels_m = loop_labels[m]
    mask_m = mask[m]
    labels_m = tf.boolean_mask(labels_m, mask_m)
```

The dimensions match for both inputs (`[512]`), but once I call `boolean_mask` the output is a tensor with 219 elements but the dimension is `[2]`. What can cause this behavior? the output shape should be [219]

Comment: Can you provide some dummy data to reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score -1):

There is a misunderstanding of what the `tf.boolean_mask()` function is supposed to return. Let's examine its usage inspired by one of the examples provided in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask#examples):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = np.array(["one", "two", "three", "four"])
mask = np.array([True, False, True, False])
result = tf.boolean_mask(tensor, mask)
```

The value of the result is `<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'one', b'three'], dtype=object)>` because only the 1st and 3rd boolean values within the 4-element mask array were `True`. For the shape of the result to be the same as the shape of the input, all values in the mask would have to be `True` to prevent removal by the mask.

Comment: That still does not explain why this function would return the shape=(2,) and an internal  numpy array containing 219 values

Comment: To reproduce your result and explain further I would need the input data.